# Javascript error when loading a page in the winforms webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control on my Windows form. I call the [this](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/argentina/primera-division-2012-2013/results/) URL.
http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/argentina/primera-division-2012-2013/results/

Then I get the following javascript error:

An error has occurred in the script on this page:

`URL: http://r1.oddsportal.com/x/global-130724112306.js`

Also, all the columns in the table, next to the soccer matches, are empty (all contain: - ) instead of decimal numbers. I believe it has something to do with the js file in the above error message.

When I open the page in the normal windows browser (IE10) it works fine, no error message and all the information on the page is present. Also, I didn't get this error message a month ago when I used my program intensively so I guess something has changed recently on the website I'm requesting.

I had no results finding a solution for this. Hopefully anyone can help!

Thanks,
Jasper

My code (easy to reproduce, just drag a webbrowser on the form, add the DocumentCompleted event and copy the code):

```
private string url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/argentina/primera-division-2012-2013/results/";

public FrmMain()
{
    webBrowser.Url = new Uri(url);
}

private void DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri == url)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```